# Web service technology to use with .NET apps and JSF

Tags: java, .net, web-services, jsf

I've got bunch of applications in .NET technologies: desktop in winforms, web in ASP.NET. I will have also a webpage wirtten in JSF. All these applications work with the same database (or databases). My problem is that all these application connect to the database (or will connect) on their own.

I want to create a gateway which will have only access to database. Other applications (in .NET and Java) will use it to get data from database. And I'm wondering which technology will be the best, for .NET and Java.

I've have to tell that I don't have much experience with Java, so I need a little help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want to create a server that encapsulates your database. This server should be used from different programming languages.
Your goal should be to use a technology that is easiy usable in these different languages.
A web-service - either using SOAP or being RESTful - comes to mind here.

Comment: like WCF? I think it is usable in JSF.. but easily? I don't know... What do you think ?

Comment: I would have suggested a RESTful service. This should be usable very easily in any environment as it doesn't need tooling or special classes. You only need simple HTTP requests.